# How can I have a horizontally shaded block title in beamer?

Tags: beamer, shading, block

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}

\setbeamertemplate{block title}[horizontal shading][left=black, right=white]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{MWE}
  \begin{block}{Title}
    Test
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The template `sidebar canvas left` can be set in this fashion; is there any way the same can be done for block titles using templates?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the way boxes are built in beamer (take a look at the definition of `\beamerboxesrounded` and `\endbeamerboxesrounded` in `beamerbaseboxes.sty` to see how different chunks are pieced together to build a box), this would require a major rewriting of the code producing the boxes and quite frankly I am not sure if the work is worthy the effort.

You can however, get this effect using the `beamer` skin for a `tcolorbox` and a convenient definition for `interior titled code` using `\shade`; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\newtcolorbox{myblock}[1][]{
  beamer,
  width=\textwidth+7pt,
  enlarge left by=-3pt,
  colback=structure,
  colframe=block body.bg,
  bottom=0pt,
  top=-2pt,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  toptitle=-1pt,
  bottomtitle=-1pt,
  fonttitle=\normalfont,
  adjusted title=#1,
  interior titled code={
    \shade[left color=Maroon!80,right color=Dandelion,middle color=Salmon] 
      (title.south west) --
      (title.south east) {[rounded corners] -- 
      (title.north east)  -- 
      (title.north west)} --
      (title.south west); 
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{The title}
This box ia a box provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{block}

\begin{myblock}[An example with \texttt{tcolorbox}]
This box looks like a box provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{myblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tcolorbox inner theme as starting point and add a shading to the block title like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
  title style={
    left color=black,
    right color=white
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{MWE}
  \begin{block}{Title}
    Test
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tcolorbox inner theme seems like a new feature ?

Comment: @JeT yes, brand new. First released the day before yesterday :) I hope it will proof useful :)

Comment: Great new feature !

Comment: @JeT I hope so! Beamer blocks are nice, but not very flexible and there are so many posts out there which go "I like beamer blocks, just want to change this tiny detail..." Currently I'm still a bit in the bug-squishing phase, that's why I was looking at so many questions to get enough test cases, but a new version should be out soon.