# How can I have a horizontally shaded frametitle in beamer?

Tags: beamer, shading

This question is similar to [How can I have a horizontally shaded block title in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174545/how-can-i-have-a-horizontally-shaded-block-title-in-beamer). I want to achieve the horizontal shading effect in the `frametitle` and when I use

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[horizontal shading]
[left=red, right=white]
```

I get compilation errors:

```
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [[]
```

Vertical shading seems to work just fine.

Comment: Which theme are you using? Can you please add a little document to your question showing the relevant settings used? In particular, I'd like to see the settings you use when you say that `frametitle` works with `vertical shading`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `shadow` outer theme and `\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading` to customize `frametitleshade`, as the following simple example illustrates:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\colorlet{titleleft}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{titleright}{white}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
  color(0pt)=(titleleft);
  color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

This, however, might not be the most convenient option since the `shadow` theme also includes a shadow below the template (which might produce undesired effects for some themes (e.g., those using a sidebar)) and the theme also redefines the headline (and this could also not be desired).

A more personal, yet involved, solution would be to define your own `frametitle` template to the shading; here's an example document showing how this could be done:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\colorlet{titleleft}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{titleright}{white}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
  color(0pt)=(titleleft);
  color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{horizontal shading}
{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  %\vskip-2pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \insertframetitle%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \strut\par%
          \else
            \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
    \vskip-2pt
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Refer to the `PGF` manual (Section **110.2 Declaring Shadings**) to customize the shading; one could, for example say

```
\colorlet{titleleft}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{titleonequarter}{orange!80!blue!30}
\colorlet{titlethreequarter}{blue!80!orange!30}
\colorlet{titleright}{green}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleonequarter,titlethreequarter,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{
  color(0pt)=(titleleft);
  color(0.25\paperwidth)=(titleonequarter);
  color(0.75\paperwidth)=(titlethreequarter);
  color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)}
```

And the result in my last example would be:

[image]

Comment: The first one works but to use the shadow theme, I cannot use my theme. The second solution worked just fine, I just adjusted it and put it in my `.sty` file. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: One more question, is there a way to adjust the gradient, i.e. the points at which the colors change?

Comment: @VagelisBebelis Sure! Please see my updated answer (the comments and example at the bottom).