# Rounded corners on costumized degraded frametitle in Beamer

Tags: beamer, rounded-corners

I want that frametitles in my Beamer presentation:

- have a smaller width than `paperwidth`
- are horizontally degraded
- have rounded corners

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226691/how-can-i-have-a-horizontally-shaded-frametitle-in-beamer) gave my the two first points described above. But I don't get how to put rounded corners.

If I add the line `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[rounded corners]` it changes nothing.

Should I indicate the parameter `rounded corners` in the `\defbeamertemplate` command? If yes, where?

Here is a related MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table},10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\colorlet{titleleft}{Red}
\colorlet{titleright}{Green}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{0.7\paperheight}{%
  color(50pt)=(titleleft);
  color(0.85\paperwidth)=(titleright)}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{horizontal shading}
{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip+3pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \insertframetitle%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \strut\par%
          \else
            \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
    \vskip-2pt
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[rounded corners]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{$\hspace{5em}$\textbf{Test}}
 a Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @samcarter Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get rounded corners I replaces `\pgfpathrectangle{}{}` by `\pgfpathrectanglecorners{}{}`. I did not find where you specified the width of your custom frametitle, so you might want to adjust the `.2` and `.8` to what you actually want.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table},10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\colorlet{titleleft}{Red}
\colorlet{titleright}{Green}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{0.7\paperheight}{%
  color(50pt)=(titleleft);
  color(0.85\paperwidth)=(titleright)}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{horizontal shading}
{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip+3pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \leftskip2.8cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \insertframetitle%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \strut\par%
          \else
            \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
%        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}} 
         \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{3mm}{3mm}}
         \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{.2\paperwidth}{0}}{\pgfpoint{.8\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
    \vskip-2pt
}
\makeatother

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large,series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
 a Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]