# Horizontally shaded title in beamer

Tags: beamer, shading

How to get a horizontally shaded title in a beamer presentation?

There are several post to do this for [block titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174545/how-can-i-have-a-horizontally-shaded-block-title-in-beamer) or [frame titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226691/how-can-i-have-a-horizontally-shaded-frametitle-in-beamer) but I did not find anything for the title of the title page.

---

Edit: I am using the Madrid theme, here is a MWE of my current configuration:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table},10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\colorlet{titleleft}{Red}
\colorlet{titleright}{Green}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{0.7\paperheight}{%
  color(50pt)=(titleleft);
  color(0.85\paperwidth)=(titleright)}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{horizontal shading}
{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip+3pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \insertframetitle%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \strut\par%
          \else
            \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
    \vskip-2pt
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[rounded corners]

\title{TEST}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{$\hspace{5em}$\textbf{Test}}
 a Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

We can clearly see that the title isn't shaded unlike the frame title.

Comment: Can you add a MWE? Which theme are you using?

Comment: @samcarter I am using the Madrid theme.

Comment: It isn't really clear to me what you want. You can add a shaded block to the title page like the one at the top of the test frame. Since title pages don't have frame titles, it will be empty, but it will be there. Or you might want a shaded block in a different place in the frame for this page. It is not at all clear. And it doesn't help that your MWE features neither a title page nor a title!

Comment: @cfr I could add a shaded frame title but it would not be centered like the `\title`command. I would like to shade the block produced by `\title`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table},10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\colorlet{titleleft}{Red}
\colorlet{titleright}{Green}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{0.7\paperheight}{%
  color(50pt)=(titleleft);
  color(0.85\paperwidth)=(titleright)}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{horizontal shading}
{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip+3pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \hskip5em
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \insertframetitle%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \strut\par%
          \else
            \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
    \vskip-2pt
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begingroup
    \centering
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
            \hskip24bp              
                \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{title}
                \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
                \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
                \else%
                \vskip0.25em%
                {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
                \fi%     
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
                }
            \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
            \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
            \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
                \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
                \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
                \pgfusepath{clip}
                \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
            \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
  \vskip-2pt    
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{author}
        \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{institute}
        \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{date}
        \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
    \endgroup
    \vfill
}
\makeatother

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white}

\title{TEST}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test}
 a Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]